# Using variable in form validation 'field' in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to understand if there is a way to use a variable in 'field' with Codeigniter form validation.

The form validation works properly when I use a text string, as shown in the first two arrays with fields 'product_name' and 'category_id', but it breaks when I try to use a variable as in the third array below.

Here is the code, load form_validation in the function:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->add_product_page_one);
```

Array that defines form rules:

```
private $add_product_page_one = array(
    array(
        'field'   => 'product_name', 
        'label'   => 'Product Name', 
        'rules'   => 'required|max_length[255]|trim|xss_clean'
    ),
    array(
        'field'   => 'category_id',
        'label'   => 'Category', 
        'rules'   => 'required|integer'
    ),
    array(
        'field'   => $this->config->item('prod_filter_db_1'), 
        'label'   => $this->config->item('prod_filter_name_1'), 
        'rules'   => 'integer'
    )
);
```

Error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/appname/application/modules/company/controllers/add.php
```

Comment: You cannot assign variables to properties. Properties can only hold constant/static values, no dynamic values.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know.  Do you have any tips for how to approach this issue? This is a white label software product that will have several iterations out there, some of the fields on the form differ based on the iteration. Our goal is to keep the code the same (except for variations which are defined in a configuration file)

Comment: Let us know where these variables have been defined?

Comment: They are defined in a configuration file, we actually call them like this: $this->config->item('prod_filter_db_1'), I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @RahilWazir thanks for the feedback. This is potentially something that we'll have to think about in more detail and come up with a solution that works with our particular structure.  However, if anyone has encountered the same issue it would be helpful to hear the way you addressed it.

Comment: i am using config values in form validation rules. try echoing out a config value to make sure you are loading the config properly.

Comment: The values display properly in our view when called within the function.  @cartalot do you have an example you can post? Thanks

Comment: well I can confirm that this does work because i've been doing it for a long time in form validation rules - and i just tried it with your code - so you are making some other mistake. Are you first loading the config file like $this->config->load('form_config') ; ? is your config file in the config folder? are you sure the names are correct? thats why i was saying to echo out the config values in your controller or model (not the view) - wherever you are doing the form validation - as a first check.

Comment: whoops ok yeah -- instead of $add_product_page_one Make it $this->add_product_page_one

Comment: which is how you have it in your set rules -- thats probably the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comments

> You cannot assign variables to properties. Properties can only hold constant/static values, no dynamic values.

You can create a private method instead of property and make sure it returns rules of arrays.

```
private function add_product_page_one() {
    return array(
        array(
            'field' => 'product_name',
            'label' => 'Product Name',
            'rules' => 'required|max_length[255]|trim|xss_clean'
        ) ,
        array(
            'field' => 'category_id',
            'label' => 'Category',
            'rules' => 'required|integer'
        ) ,
        array(
            'field' => $this->config->item('prod_filter_db_1') ,
            'label' => $this->config->item('prod_filter_name_1') ,
            'rules' => 'integer'
        )
    );
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
// call the private method
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->add_product_page_one());
```